# How to display partial view on Details page

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, interface

I am working on an auction site in ASP.NET MVC and I have a details page for my Item model. On this detail page I have a link to the "Create" Bid page. On my create page is just a simple textbox to enter the user's max bid.

> I was wondering if there was a way to put this form directly on my "Details" page, (maybe with a partial view)?

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a modal window would allow you to keep the user in place while setting their maximum bid.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWotXT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This would also provide you with a convenient place to put additional bidding options in the future if you find a need for them.

Comment: I think a popup window would suit my needs well. So I need to setup a partial view with my "Create" page to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure how your project is structured or what technologies you are using, but yes, that could very well be one way to do it. If you'd like further assistance with issues you run into on the implementation side of things, unfortunately we can't help you here, but Stack Overflow could. There are many, many existing modal implementations that work in conjunction with major front-end libraries (Angular, jQuery, etc). I'd start by searching for an existing plugin for the frameworks you may already have included.